# Woocommerce remove tool tip on admin product edit page

Tags: woocommerce

Looking for a code snippet to remove the text section 'Upload jpeg files that are 1000 x 1000 pixels or larger (max. 50 mb)' on the woocommerce admin product edit page.

'page inspection' shows it to be the line: image-added-detail

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that notice via the following hook:

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function() {
    remove_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wc_product_post_thumbnail_html' );
});
```

This goes into the functions.php of your child theme or can be added via a plugin like Code Snippets.